# How do I get the latest commit of public git repo in my gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, rubygems, simple-form

in my gemfile i have the following

```
gem 'simple_form'
```

I want to grab the latest commit of [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). The current release version 2.1.0. But there are things in the latest commit that I would like to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Gemfile you can point a gem to its github path, something like this:

```
gem 'simple_form', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'
```

This way it'll point to the master branch, you can also define a specific branch with

```
gem 'simple_form', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git', branch: 'some_branch'
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `branch` (as @Miguelgraz correctly suggests), you can point your `Gemfile` to a specific `ref` of a Git repo:

```
gem 'simple_form', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git', :ref => 'd7a661'
```

Don't forget to re-run `bundle install`.

There's more info at [Bundler git reference](http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html).

Comment: Great addition, I totally forgot the `ref:` parameter.